# DynamoDB modeling relational data (restaurant menus example)

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, relational

I'm creating a web platform on AWS to enable restaurant owners in my community to create menus. I'm moving from a relational database model to a NoSQL solution and wondering the best way to organize this data. My current relational model is as follows:

```
Table 'restaurants': id (int / primary key), name, owner (int)
Table 'categories': id (int / primary key), restaurant (int), parent (int)
Table 'items': id (primary key), name, category (int)
```

Only the owner should be allowed to create/update/delete places, categories, and items.

What would you recommend as a de-normalized solution given the ownership constraint? I was thinking of doing the following:

```
Table 'restaurants': id (primary key), owner (sort key), categories (list of ids)
Table 'categories':  id (primary key), restaurant (id), items (list of item objects), subcategories (list of category ids)
```

Wondering if it'd be better to have all category data contained within the restaurant table. As an example, a user should only be able to add an item to a category if they are the owner of the associated restaurant, which would take an additional query, per above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends mostly how you use your data . If usually the Restaurant is read full, is ok to have all in the restaurants table.

If you have a lot of operations only on one category , for example many are interested only in food and not interested in drinks , then it would be good to have this done on categories.

I think for some restaurants would be better to have it split in categories and keep common data on restaurant level , address, phone , opening hours and so on .

I don't think write is important , seems to be over 90% read web site.0

Perhaps a cache solution ? Redis ? Memcache ? this would speed up even more.